# Tarea de gulp tarda muchísimo cuando se ejecuta en servidor

Tags: nodejs, apache, ubuntu, gulp, xubuntu

Tengo un server web que utilizo como sandbox para hacer pruebas de desarrollo web.

Sus especificaciones son:

> Ubuntu server 16.04 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N2800   @ 1.86GHz
>
> MemTotal:        4018884 kB
>
> MemFree:         1456208 kB
>
> MemAvailable:    3512600 kB

El servidor corre actualmente con apache con fast-cgi.

Cuando hago una tarea de gulp en entorno local tarda alrededor de 3 segundos en acabar.
La misma tarea en el sevidor tarde sobre 29 segundos.

Ambos proyectos son clones del mismo repositorio, por lo que creo que deberian de tardar lo mismo, o al menos un tiempo aproximado y no esta diferencia.

He instalado el modulo de npm *time-require* y este es el **output**:

```
    [18:45:39] Starting 'sass'...
[18:45:40] Starting 'js'...
[18:45:58] Version: webpack 1.15.0
      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    main.js   1.8 kB       0  [emitted]  main
main.js.map  1.84 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[18:45:58] Finished 'sass' after 19 s
[18:45:58] Finished 'js' after 19 s
[18:45:58] Starting 'build'...
[18:45:58] Finished 'build' after 80 μs
[18:45:58] Starting 'default'...
[18:45:58] Finished 'default' after 33 μs


Start time: (2017-07-20 16:45:36 UTC) [treshold=1%]
 #  module                                                                                         time  %
 1  ./lib/src (node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js)                                            249ms  ▇▇ 1%
 2  vinyl-fs (node_modules/vinyl-fs/index.js)                                                     370ms  ▇▇ 2%
 3  gulp (node_modules/gulp/index.js)                                                             405ms  ▇▇ 2%
 4  svgo (node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo.js)                                                          287ms  ▇▇ 1%
 5  postcss-svgo (node_modules/postcss-svgo/dist/index.js)                                        298ms  ▇▇ 1%
 6  ../data/prefixes (node_modules/autoprefixer/data/prefixes.js)                                 324ms  ▇▇ 1%
 7  autoprefixer (node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js)                                  701ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
 8  cssnano (node_modules/cssnano/dist/index.js)                                                   1.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
 9  gulp-cssnano (node_modules/gulp-cssnano/index.js)                                              1.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
10  gulp-sourcemaps (node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/index.js)                                       290ms  ▇▇ 1%
11  ./Compiler (node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js)                                             243ms  ▇ 1%
12  ./WebpackOptionsApply (node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js)                       339ms  ▇▇ 1%
13  ./validateSchema (node_modules/webpack/lib/validateSchema.js)                                 351ms  ▇▇ 2%
14  webpack (node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js)                                                 999ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 4%
15  ./Compiler (node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js)                 297ms  ▇▇ 1%
16  webpack (node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js)                     517ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
17  ./path (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js)                                        528ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
18  babel-traverse (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js)                                     585ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
19  babel-template (node_modules/babel-template/lib/index.js)                                     771ms  ▇▇▇▇ 3%
20  ./helpers (node_modules/babel-helpers/lib/helpers.js)                                         801ms  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
21  babel-helpers (node_modules/babel-helpers/lib/index.js)                                       814ms  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
22  ../transformation/file (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js)              1.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇ 5%
23  ./lib/api/node.js (node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js)                                    1.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇ 5%
24  babel-core (node_modules/babel-core/index.js)                                                  1.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇ 5%
25  /home/u2487/trunk/node_modules/babel-lo....js (node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)   1.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 6%
26  /home/u2487/trunk/node_modules/babel-pr...de_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js)  262ms  ▇▇ 1%
Total require(): 3750
Total time: 22.8s
```

Y este es el **gulpfile** que estoy utilizando:

```
    'use strict'
require("time-require")
var gulp = require('gulp')
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var nano = require('gulp-cssnano')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
var webpack = require('webpack-stream')
var wpOpt = require('webpack').optimize
var named = require('vinyl-named')
var sassTypes = require('node-sass').types
var Svgo = require('svgo')

var paths = require('./package.json').buildPaths

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  var _svgo = new Svgo()
  var svgOptimize = _svgo.optimize.bind(_svgo)
  var sassOpts = {
    functions: {
      'uri-encode($val)': function uriEncode(val) {
        return new sassTypes.String(encodeURIComponent(val.getValue()))
      },
      'svgo($val)': function svgo(val, done) {
        svgOptimize(val.getValue(), function(result) {
          done(new sassTypes.String(result.data))
        })
      },
    },
  }

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    return gulp.src(paths.sass.i)
      .pipe(
        sass(sassOpts).on('error', sass.logError)
      )
      .pipe(nano())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sass.o))

  } else {

    return gulp.src(paths.sass.i)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(
        sass(sassOpts).on('error', sass.logError)
      )
      .pipe(nano())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sass.o))

  }
})


gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.s{c,a}ss', ['sass'])
})

gulp.task('js', function () {
  var conf = require('./webpack.config.js')

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    delete conf.devtool
    conf.plugins.push(new wpOpt.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
      },
      mangle: {
        except: ['$', '$super', 'exports', 'require'],
      },
    }))

  }

  return gulp.src(paths.js.i)
    .pipe(named())
    .pipe(webpack(conf))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js.o))

})

gulp.task('js:watch', function () {
  var conf = require('./webpack.config.js')
  conf.watch = true

  // Webpack logs its own errors. Just swallow error to not break watch
  var wp = webpack(conf).on('error', function handleWebpackError() {this.emit('end')})

  return gulp.src(paths.js.i)
    .pipe(named())
    .pipe(wp)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js.o))

})


gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function () {
  gulp.start('sass:watch')
  gulp.start('js:watch')
})

gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'js'])

gulp.task('default', ['build'])
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna pista de lo que puede ser?

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Se que es un poco ajeno a la pregunta, pero te recomentaría que a producción subas solo los css/js definitivos, y las tareas gulp las ejecutes en tu equipo.

Comment: @DiegoMartin cualquier apreciacion es bien recibida :)
Lo tenemos planteado asi por que al trabajar varias personas en el mismo proyecto, haciendo la compilacion en local, nos salen conflictos al subir el archivo compilado al servidor muy a menudo.

Comment: Hombre, esta claro que todo depende como lo tengáis montado, pero yo en la empresa que estoy actualmente, lo que hacemos es no sincronizar el código css en el repositorio git, pero si los less (en vuestro caso sass) y solo cuando alguien lo va a subir a producción es cuando sube los css que le genera el gulp. Así evitamos tener que meter cosas que puedan ocupar y relantizar producción. En este caso evitaríamos meter node en producción.

Comment: Con respecto a la duda, me he fijado, que el servidor tiene de memoria libre 1'4GB, lo cual no es mucho, y puede ser que en vuestros equipos donde desarrolláis tengáis más memoria, podría ser parte del motivo.

Comment: No debería representar ningún inconveniente si el server es decente y, cuando digo decente, es un server normal. En mi caso, tenemos dos servidores, uno para testing y otro para producción; la aplicación está hecha en React y usando Webpack para generar los bundles en ambos servidores no toma más de 5-6s (~2mb es el peso del bundle generado). Obviamente las especificaciones no son las óptimas para un servidor, el procesador es de gama baja, solo tiene dos núcleos, si hay otros procesos ocupando procesador, olvídate...